# MySQL Inserted Multiple Times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple `php script` with `mysql`.

I'm using `XAMPP` version 3.2.1 I also tried on `WAMP` SERVER same effect insert 3 or more rows in every refresh or whenever I tried to run my script...

**Problem php script inserted 3 rows or more every refresh this is my code**

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES ( "user@yahoo.com", "user", "password" )';

mysql_select_db('chie');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

**This is my Table:**

```
create table users(
    users_id int(22) auto_increment not null unique,
    email varchar(64) not null,
    username varchar(64) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(users_id)
    );
```

Comment: try putting `mysql_select_db` before your `sql query`...

Comment: Is this the only piece of code you have in that page ?

Comment: Validate the form before submit. and after submit clear the values

Comment: Another method is to redirect the page after submit

Comment: I called my script by url: localhost/index.php... Im building my own PHP Framework when I notice that every time I call my script it inserted 3 rows or more... Soo I created a very simple php script like on my question and put it on index.php alone...

Answer (score 1):

please review this code

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES ( "user@yahoo.com", "user", "password" )';

mysql_select_db('chie');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
```

please remove `if(! $retval ){}` ,because this will make your query to run once again ,so it will get inserted again and redirect page using `header('location:somepage.php')`

Comment: Thanks redirect only hahahaha! I have to redirect after insert!

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything, but can you tell me how your PHP code is called ?

Anyway, check that your page is not included somewhere a few times, or you are not in a loop.

Comment: I called my script by url: localhost/index.php... Im building my own PHP Framework when I notice that every time I call my script it inserted 3 rows or more... Soo I created a very simple php script like on my question and put it on index.php alone...